# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable dictionary python

Tags: python, pandas

**The code**

```
import pandas as pd
import clearbit
import json
clearbit.key = 'sk_1915de5d2d7b6e245d6613e3d2188368'
df = pd.read_csv("/home/vipul/Desktop/new.csv", sep=',', encoding="utf-8")

saved_column = df['Company']
print(saved_column)
i=0
NoneType = type(None)
for data in saved_column:   

    n = saved_column[i]
    i = i+1
    data = clearbit.NameToDomain.find(name=n)
    print(data)
    df['domain'][i] = data['domain']

df.to_csv("/home/vipul/Desktop/new.csv",index = False, skipinitialspace=False)

print("File saved to desktop as new.csv")
```

How to handle the type none object and store some default value in the csv file corresponding company name

**new.csv:**

```
Company
‎Accenture
‎AND Digital
‎Accenture
‎Kite Consulting Group
‎Capgemini
‎Accenture
‎Capgemini
‎Accenture UK
‎Accenture
```

**print(data)**

```
Name: Company, dtype: object
{'domain': 'accenture.com', 'logo': 'https://logo.clearbit.com/accenture.com', 'name': 'Accenture'}
{'domain': 'and.digital', 'logo': 'https://logo.clearbit.com/and.digital', 'name': 'AND Digital'}
{'domain': 'accenture.com', 'logo': 'https://logo.clearbit.com/accenture.com', 'name': 'Accenture'}
None
{'domain': 'capgemini.com', 'logo': 'https://logo.clearbit.com/capgemini.com', 'name': 'Capgemini'}
{'domain': 'accenture.com', 'logo': 'https://logo.clearbit.com/accenture.com', 'name': 'Accenture'}
{'domain': 'capgemini.com', 'logo': 'https://logo.clearbit.com/capgemini.com', 'name': 'Capgemini'}
None
{'domain': 'accenture.com', 'logo': 'https://logo.clearbit.com/accenture.com', 'name': 'Accenture'}
```

This has none type which gives type error

Answer (score 0):

You can save the `data['domain']` in a list first and then assign it to df

```
res = []
for data in saved_column:   

    n = saved_column[i]
    i = i+1
    data = clearbit.NameToDomain.find(name=n)
    if data:
        res.append(data.get('domain', None))

df['domain'] = res
df.to_csv("/home/vipul/Desktop/new.csv",index = False, skipinitialspace=False)

print("File saved to desktop as new.csv")
```

Comment: **error**  `res.append(data['domain'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Looks like your data variable is empty. I have updated snippet to check this condition

Comment: @Rakesh - In my opinion there is problem with `NaN`s ;)

Comment: no the error is still there **type error**    `res.append(data.get('domain', None))
TypeError: get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: should we have an try block ? have you tried the code ? can i send you the csv file ?